# properly use animation to slide text up using css3 animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to create animation effect where each line of the text slide up on load, only using css.

Would this be the proper way? I feel that there is a better way to implement. I dont like how i am using keyframes to change the padding and line-height in order to have the slide up effect after each sentence

Thanks for the help!

HTML

```
<p class="slide-up">
  Here is the first sentence that should slide up 
  </br>
  This is the second sentence that should slide up right after it with a delay
</p>
```

CSS

```
p {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
    
@keyframes slide-up {
  from {
    padding-top: 100px;
    opacity: .25;
    line-height: 80px;
  }
  to {
    padding-top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    ine-height: 25px;
  }
}
    
.slide-up {
  animation: slide-up 1s;
}
```

JS FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/91ypg7Ls/

Comment: Could try removing `padding` properties from `keyframes`.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question depends on opinionated answer, have a look at this:

```
@keyframes slide-up {
    from {

        opacity: .25;
        line-height: 500px;
    }
    to {

        opacity: 1;
        line-height: 25px;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/91ypg7Ls/2/